# python exe starts and stops immediately on windows 10

Tags: python

Hey guys I created a program, used pyinstaller --onedir 'name' and created the exe.

Now I am having an issue while it works perfectly on my computer (windows 7) when I took the dist folder to a windows 10 machine the cmd window started and closed at once without running and without giving out an error message (or it was fast enough that I could not see it).

Is this an issue with windows 10 or did I do anything wrong when compiling to exe?

Comment: you mean a python executable file?

Comment: yeah, I had the pyprogram.py and created the pyprogram.exe, the exe doesn't work.

Comment: "the cmd window started and closed at once" What happens when you use an already existing cmd window to run the program (by typing e.g `./pyprogram.exe` at the prompt)?

Comment: the error is : ImportError: DLL load failed while importing aggregations: 
The specified function could not be detected. unit.
[2532] Failed to execute script eopyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that probably your dist directory requires different dlls, probably some system ones that you need to add them into your one directory executable so that everything is linked correctly.

One way to find the missing dependencies of your exe is to use Processor monitor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon in your Win 10. You see the traces of your process and then you investigate.

One other way is to install Process explorer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer and check the dlls that did load to see where it stops.

There is also https://dependencywalker.com/ which is really powerful, but when I used it in similar scenarios, it didn't help me that much.

Also have a look at the possible errors that pyinstaller might raise, even the slightest warning can be helpful.

One other concern would be the machine you are using: let's say you have a generated process which contains dlls with 64 bits that you are trying to run in a machine with 32 bits.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks mate I will test it in a couple of hours and tell you.

Comment: What you said seems to be correct. The program is trying to use the 64bit to the 32 and it doesn't work. I will try to add the dlls and see how it goes